# QueryBuilder Modifying Entered Query

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, ms-access-2007, query-builder

Why does QueryBuilder modify my query?  Is there a workaround?

When I enter the query below, QueryBuilder modifies the query to the more complex version below, requiring additional parameters for the FillBy method.  Any additional parameters adds an exponential amount of complexity to the modified query.

Entered:

```
SELECT prop, lot, type, created_on, done
  FROM TestSelection
 WHERE (prop=? OR '_NO_PROP_'=?) AND (lot=? OR '_NO_LOT_'=?)
```

Modified:

```
SELECT prop, lot, type, created_on, done
FROM   TestSelection
WHERE  (prop = ?) AND (lot = ?) OR
       (prop = ?) AND ('_NO_LOT_' = ?) OR
       (lot = ?) AND ('_NO_PROP_' = ?) OR
       ('_NO_LOT_' = ?) AND ('_NO_PROP_' = ?)
```

Goal: Allow the user to search by prop, lot, or both.  My actual program will query on several additional fields.

Notes:

- WinForms Project (VB.NET if applicable)
- TestSelection is a query in a Microsoft Access database

Comment: First off, if you want to search by either or both, should the query simply be prop=? OR lot=? Currently the search needs to exist in either prop or _no_prop_ as well as exist in either lot or _no_lot_, is this intended?

It looks like query builder is automatically distributing the And accross the () groupings...

Comment: I will provide the constants `_NO_PROP_` and `_NO_LOT_` in the VB code if the corresponding field is empty.  No, it should be `AND` not `OR`.  The conditions reworded are return a row if (prop: not specified OR matches) AND (lot: not specified OR matches).

Comment: So the following combinations return rows:
A not specified AND B not specified,
A matches AND B not specified,
A not specified AND B matches,
A matches AND B matches

Are those conditions what you expect?

Comment: Correct those combinations work... but the boolean logic distributing creates an exponential amount of parameters for the created `FillBy` function.  Which isn't really a problem... but just ridiculous as far as readability goes... especially since my actual scenario would have about eight optional criteria fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to remove any WHERE conditions in QueryBuilder.  Instead, I just use a LINQ query.